# columnfamily setup for nested structure cassandra

Tags: model, cassandra

I have data which is nested like -

```
a -> bb (multiple columns name values for bb)
a -> bb -> ccc (multiple columnn name values for ccc)
a -> bb -> ddd (multiple columnn name values for ddd)
a -> cc -> eee (multiple columns name values for eee)
p -> qq
p -> qq -> rrr 
p -> qq -> rrr -> ssss -> ttttt......
....
```

For input 'a' , i need to get all things under 'a'.
For input 'bb' all things under 'bb' and so on.

With no defined limit on nesting, what will be the best way to model it in cassandra.
With composite column, i need to know how many nesting levels in advance so i am not sure thats going to work out well.
i.e. composite column like (a:bb:ccc) will break if i encounter more nested structure.

Any suggestions........

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into using maps/dicts as column type? This [post](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cql3_collections) explains the different collection types available in Cassandra

Answer (score 0):

So that looks like a graph database.  You should probably use titan db http://thinkaurelius.github.io/titan/ which implements a graph database on top of Cassandra.

If you want to re-invent it on your own, any time you want to insert something, you can insert it multiple times with different key prefixes.  So to insert `p -> qq -> rrr -> ssss -> ttttt`

Insert:

```
p : qq -> rrr -> ssss -> ttttt
p -> qq : rrr -> ssss -> ttttt
p -> qq -> rrr : ssss -> ttttt
p -> qq -> rrr -> ssss : ttttt
p -> qq -> rrr -> ssss -> ttttt : <empty>
```

You could theoretically use the "DynamicComposite" type from your code to have the variable length tuples, but that would make using the database from the command line tools, or really anything besides your code, harder.  Probably better to just use strings with separators.  Also use a batch so that the writes all fail or succeed together.

```
begin batch
insert into XYZ (prefix, suffix) values ('p', 'qq:rrr:ssss:ttttt');
insert into XYZ (prefix, suffix) values ('p:qq', 'rrr:ssss:ttttt');
insert into XYZ (prefix, suffix) values ('p:qq:rrr', 'ssss:ttttt');
insert into XYZ (prefix, suffix) values ('p:qq:rrr:ssss', 'ttttt');
insert into XYZ (prefix) values ('p:qq:rrr:sass:ttttt');
apply batch;
```

Then to get all the values under `p->qq->rr` you would just:

```
select * from XYZ where prefix = 'p:qq:rrr';
```

Comment: Thanks Zanson. what i have decided is to put reference ID for each level like -   
RowKey  :  Columns
    p        :  id1 | id2 | id3...
    p.qq     :  id1 | id3
    p.qq.rrr :  id3

Comment: repeating what i earlier was trying to post -
 what i have decided is to put reference ID for each level like -   
RowKey  :  Columns
    p        :  id1 | id2 | id3...
    p.qq     :  id1 | id3
    p.qq.rrr :  id3
and have details for each id in one row like -
    details | id1 -<>| id2 -<>| id3 -<>...

This makes details row big in the sense all id details will be in one row. But i will always query columns by column names only. Do you see any problem with this design...Every request to get all id details will get completed in two queries- query Ids and then details for all Ids